# How does UIScrollView change the frame, but not the bounds? How does UIScrollView work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I understand the difference between frames and bounds I think, bounds are to the view's local coordinate system, while frames are to the superviews.

With scrollviews however, I'm a little confused.

When I have a UIImageView in a UIScrollView and pinch to zoom it larger, it seems the frame grows larger (width and height) increases the width and height of the corresponding UIImage as well.

However, it seems like the bounds of the UIImageView don't change at all.

Why is this? How do scroll views work in regards to all of this? I've read multiple questions and checked the documentation but this explanation is eluding me.

How does zooming in a UIScrollView affect its contents? Does it just change the frame of the zooming view but somehow not the bounds?

Comment: The frame doesn't change, nor do the bounds. The scroll view adjusts the transform of its content view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the explanation [in my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_zooming):

> The scroll view zooms by applying a scaling transform to the scalable view; therefore the frame of the scalable view is scaled as well. Moreover, the scroll view is concerned to make scrolling continue to work correctly: the limits as the user scrolls should continue to match the limits of the content, and commands like scrollRectToVisible:animated: should continue to work the same way for the same values. Therefore, the scroll view automatically scales its own contentSize to match the current zoomScale. (You can actually detect this happening by overriding setContentSize in a UIScrollView subclass: you can see the scroll view adjusting its own content size as you zoom.)

Basically (though that is not quite clear from the above quotation) we have no business concerning ourselves with the frame of the scalable view - or *any* view - that has a non-identity transform applied to it, which is exactly the case here. That fact is made very clear by the Apple documentation on UIView. Thus you should not be looking at the frame - only the transform. The frame *value* that your are reading changes purely as a side-effect of the transform change.

As for the bounds of the scalable view - obviously the bounds do not change; that is the whole point of how a transform works. It maintains a constant `center` and `bounds`, so that subviews and drawing continue to operate correctly within the frame-of-reference coordinates despite the transform. My book [talks you through](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_transform) an understanding of this as well.

On the other hand, the scroll view's own bounds can certainly change their origin, not least because that is exactly and identically what it means for a scroll view to scroll. Scrolling *is* a change of bounds origin, plain and simple. And this would not be surprising during zooming, because, as I just said, the content size has changed, so the content may be repositioned in order to keep displaying it coherently as you zoom.

Comment: For the last paragraph, are you referring to the bounds of the scroll view or the bounds of the image view? When I play around with Apple's PhotoScroller demo, and watch the scroll view's values as it moves, the uncommented lines in this code are the only ones that change: http://i.imgur.com/QtWp85k.png The image view, as you outlined, but the bounds of the scrollview clearly change when zooming in and panning, which changes the origin.

Comment: That is what scrolling _is_. Again, see my book (I already gave you a link) on how a scroll view works. It works by changing the bounds origin - just as you would do with any view in order to "scroll" the position of its subviews. However, your question was about zooming, not scrolling, so I didn't discuss that in my answer.

Comment: Edited to clarify (and to show the linkage between zooming and secondary scrolling).